# Wildcard class as variable in constructor

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have class A

```
class A{}
```

class A1 extends class A

```
class A1 extends A{}
```

now in class B, I want to pass any class that extends class A as a variable.

```
class B{
    Class<? extends A> variable;

    public B(Class<? extends A> variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
}
```

to run above, the driver class is as below

```
 class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b=new B(new A());// A cannot be converted to Class<? extends A>.
        B b=new B(new A1());// A1 cannot be converted to Class<? extends A>.
            }
}
```

because `Class<? extends A> variable` it means, any class extending class A can be passed in the constructor and A1 is extending A, then why its giving error?

what am I missing?

Comment: You are passing instances instead of the classes. Either pass the classes or change the signature to accept instances instead.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that what you're actually trying to do is to set up `B` so it can work with *instances* of `A` or any subtype of `A`. To do that, you'll need to make the class `B` itself generic:

```
class B<T extends A> {
    T variable;

    public B(T variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B<A> b = new B<>(new A());
        B<A1> b1 = new B<>(new A1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Class<? extends A> variable` means that `variable` can hold a reference to an object of type `Class`, not to something that extends `A`.

`Class` is a "meta-class", its purpose is to describe another class. From a `Class` instance you can get all the fields and all the methods that this class provides. You can take a look to the [Java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) tutorial for more informations.

To make your code work you can write something like this:

```
class B<T extends A> {
    private T variable;
    public B(T variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B<A> b = new B<>(new A());
        B<A1> b1 = new B<>(new A1());
    }
}
```

In this way you're creating a generic class `B` which accepts instances of `A` or something that extends `A`

Answer (score 1):

What would work instead is:

```
B b = new B(A.class); // class type expected and not the instance of
```

or

```
B b = new B(A1.class);
```

---

To explain further, parameter `Class<? extends A> variable` means that `<? extends A>` is the type of the class modeled by the supplied `Class` object. Hence you need to supply either class `A` or any class extending `A` as an argument but of type `Class`.